# Django: fullcalendar drag events and save

Tags: django, save, fullcalendar, getjson

I 'm trying to drag the events and store them in the database with getJSON

javascript file :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>



function saveMyData(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta) {

 $.getJSON("{% url events_drag %}", {'title': event.title, 'start': event.start,
                                 'end': event.end},  function(data) {

                                     });   

}
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#eventFilterCalendar').fullCalendar({
eventDrop: function(event,  dayDelta, minuteDelta) {

    saveMyData(event);

},


eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta) {
            saveMyData(event);
         },

</script>
```

views :

```
def eventsdrag(request):
  print 'events...'
  untitre= request.GET['title']
  unstart= request.GET['start']
  unend= request.GET['end']

  print 'untitre', untitre
  print 'unstart', unstart
  print 'unend', unend

  Event.title = untitre
  Event.start = unstart
  Event.end = unend
  Event.save()

  event_list = []

  event_list.append({
            ...
            'start': Event.start,
            'end': Event.end,
            'title': Event.title,


            })


  return http.HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_list),
                         content_type='application/json')
```

model :

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_(u"Nom de l'étude"), max_length=100)
    start = models.DateTimeField(_(u"début"))
    end = models.DateTimeField(_('fin'))
```

the function eventdrag should read event.title, event.start, event.end and save them in the database

but request.GET don't work..I display 'events..' and nothing else..

Comment: Can you use a good indentation even in JS ? Your first code is not readable.

Comment: I simplified and forget parenthesis...but it's readable..

Comment: 'eventDrop: function(event,  dayDelta, minuteDelta)' is a closure that is evaluated once when jQuery binds the event. You should grab these arguments in the event function saveMyData when it's called

Comment: if I put inside savemydata : alert(event.title); or alert(event.start); or alert(event.end), I display the title, start and end but why getjson dont send nothing to the function eventsdrag ?